Total internal reflection from underwater absent ambient light
I’m writing about an underwater civilization, and have questions about what the people would see looking upward. I know that in daylight, total internal reflection would make the surface of the water above them appear as a mirror, except for a circular region directly above the observer. My question is whether, at night, the field of view would still be restricted, particularly on a moonless night.

When passing in front of the windows of a darkened shop one is able to see their reflection in the windows and use them as mirrors, for example to check one's appearance; that's because even at very low angles of incidence, a small part of the light is reflected by the glass (about 2%, just as for water), and, when there is no or very little light coming from the other side, this small amount of reflected light is enough to form an image.
If the underwater civilization has sources of light of their own, in a moonless night the entire surface will appear as a mirror, possibly distorted if the surface is not perfectly still; if they do not have light sources of their own, then in a moonless night there is nothing to see anyway.
Fun experiment: put some water in a pail, wait for the surface to become still, then look inside. You will see your reflection as in a mirror. In Greek mythology, this is how Narcissus fell in love with his own image, giving us the word narcissism.

Total internal reflection is a property of the pair of media through which light propagate (water and air in your case) and doesn't depend on the time of the day.
Day or night, total internal reflection will still happen and the field of view will stay the same. What will change is the amount of available light and therefore what and how clearly it can be seen.
